getting events from Nemo guardrails in streaming mode
I want to get the events from Nemo guardrails when in streaming mode. I can get then in non-streaming mode, but have not figured out how to get them in streaming.
In non-streaming I do this:
        response_gen = await app.generate_async(messages=history, options={
            "log": {
                "activated_rails": True,
                "llm_calls": True,
                "internal_events": True,
                "colang_history": True
            }
        })
        events = response_gen.log.internal_events

But I have not found a way do to his when streaming
response_gen = app.stream_async(messages=history)

